# Jquery dimensions calculator

Tags: jquery, math, calculator, addition, subtraction

I have a friend who works for a company selling radiator covers and have been asked to add a dimension calculator to their site so people can add their measurements and extras and purchase online.

The meat and potatoes of the code is working but for some reason the price is being updated in the wrong sides of the decimal point.

Here is my example code on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/AndyDyas/tw62Lzop/48/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <label for="a">Width:</label>
        <input type="number" name="a" id="a" value="1000" placeholder="1000"  /><br>
    <label for="b">Height:</label>
        <input type="number" name="b" id="b" value="800" placeholder="800" /><br>
    <label for="c">Depth:</label>
        <input type="number" name="c" id="c" value="15" placeholder="15" /><br>   
    <label for="d">Colour:</label>
        <select name="colour" id="d">
          <option value="0">Select</option>
          <option value="-15">Primed (-£15)</option>
          <option value="50">Gloss (+£50)</option>
          <option value="40">Own Colour (£40)</option>
        </select> <br> 
    <label for="e">Grille:</label>
        <select name="grille" id="e">
          <option value="0">Select</option>
          <option value="40">Slats (+£40)</option>
          <option value="75">Regency Brass (+£75)</option>
          <option value="150">Regency Antique / Chrome (+£150)</option>
          <option value="40">Gold / Silver SAA (+£40)</option>
        </select> <br>           
    <label for="total">Result:</label>
        <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="260.00"  />
    </div>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var price = jQuery('#total').val();
        function compute() {
          var a = parseFloat(jQuery('#a').val() - jQuery('#a').attr("placeholder"));
          var b = parseFloat(jQuery('#b').val() - jQuery('#b').attr("placeholder"));
          var c = parseFloat(jQuery('#c').val() - jQuery('#c').attr("placeholder"));
          var d = parseFloat(jQuery('#d').val()).toFixed(2);
          var e = parseFloat(jQuery('#e').val()).toFixed(2);
          var total = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + parseFloat(c) + parseFloat(d) + parseFloat(e) + parseFloat(price);
          jQuery('#total').val(parseFloat(total).toFixed(2));
          //alert(a);
        }
        jQuery('#a, #b, #c, #d, #e').change(compute);        
      });;
    </script>
</div>
```

What needs to happen is for every extra mm in the width/height/depth 10p needs to be added to the price but for some reason it's adding it on the wrong side of the decimal point (adding £1 instead of 10p) and the opposite for the colour and grille which is in pounds.

Hope this load of mess makes sense and i would be very very grateful for some help with this.

Cheers

Andy

Comment: `var total = parseFloat(a + b + c + d + e + parseFloat(price);` is not valid. You are missing a bracket. Please click edit, the `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] HERE instead of at an external site that can disappear

Comment: Always check the error console...

Comment: i have fixed the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the opportunity to rewrite the code to be more extensible and flexible

- made an object to hold the values and the price changes
- look up these settings on load to set the defaults
- validate the required fields on change
- cast the field values to numbers

```js
// this object is the basis for all fields
const prices = {
  "base" : 260,
  "width":  { "min": 1000, "extra": 0.1  },
  "height": { "min":  800, "extra": 0.15 },
  "depth":  { "min": 15,   "extra": 0    } // correct?
};
// helper function to cast to number from string
const toNum = str => isNaN(str) || str.trim() === "" ? 0 : +str;


const compute = e => {
  if (e) e.target.reportValidity(); // show error if field is emptied
  let width = toNum($('#width').val()),
     height = toNum($('#height').val()),
      depth = toNum($('#depth').val()),
     colour = toNum($('#colour').val()),
     grille = toNum($('#grille').val()),
  widthPrice  = (width - prices["width"].min)*prices["width"].extra,
  heightPrice  = (height - prices["height"].min)*prices["height"].extra,
  depthPrice  = (depth - prices["depth"].min)*prices["depth"].extra,
  total = prices["base"] + widthPrice + heightPrice + depthPrice + colour + grille;
  if (total < prices["base"]) total = prices["base"]; // not possible to get less than base price
  $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
};


$(function() {
  // setting the defaults based on the object at the top
  ["width","height","depth"]
    .forEach(field => ["min","placeholder","value"]
      .forEach(attr => $('#'+field).attr(attr,prices[field].min))
  )    
      
  compute();
  $('#computeDiv').on("input", compute);
});
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>The basic unit is 1000mm wide by 800mm tall and costs £260.00</p>
<p>Every extra 1mm in width is an additional 10 pence per mm and every extra 1mm in height is an extra 15 pence per mm.</p>
<p>The dropdowns are simple extra features at fixed costs there is only the width and height that are dynamic.</p>
<p>So a unit that is 1001mm x 801mm would cost £260.25 (£260 + 10p + 15p) </p>

<div id="computeDiv">
  <label for="width">Width (mm):</label> <input type="number" name="width" id="width" value="" required/><br>
  <label for="height">Height (mm):</label> <input type="number" name="height" id="height" value="" required /><br>
  <label form="depth">Depth (mm):</label> <input type="number" name="depth" id="depth" value="" required /><br>
  <label for="colour">Colour:</label>
  <select name="colour" id="colour">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="-15">Primed (-£15)</option>
    <option value="50">Gloss (+£50)</option>
    <option value="40">Own Colour (£40)</option>
  </select><br>
  <label for="grille">Grille:</label>
  <select name="grille" id="grille">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="40">Slats (+£40)</option>
    <option value="75">Regency Brass (+£75)</option>
    <option value="150">Regency Antique / Chrome (+£150)</option>
    <option value="40">Gold / Silver SAA (+£40)</option>
  </select><br>
  <label>Total:</label>
  <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="0.00" readonly />
</div>
```

Comment: im deducting the placeholder because i need to capture the value above the initial one.

So if i the width is 1001 the price should be 264.10 not 265.00

Hope this makes sense

Comment: no its still adding the number to the wrong side of the decimal point.

Comment: the Colour and Grille are working as they should be but when the values of Width/Height/Depth are changed for every 1 it needs to add 10 pence so the price would be £260.10 not £261.00. At the moment its adding the extra as £1 instead of 10 pence.

thanks for your help.

Comment: I think we need to rethink this completely

Comment: i have spent a week coming up with what i had. its so confusing.

Comment: This is an example of what im trying to recreate https://radiatorcabinetsuk.co.uk/product/chiltern-traditional-radiator-cabinets/?fbclid=IwAR1TRK2XCrH7DVK2NokawG99m-LAWKmUwzZydBf0EXgtrcripxhFnu5IoVc

Comment: Sorry this is so complicated it took me while to figure out but i will try and explain with an example.

The basic unit is 1000mm wide by 800mm tall and costs £260.00

Every extra 1mm in width is an additional 10 pence per mm and every extra 1mm in height is an extra 15 pence per mm.

The dropdowns are simple extra features at fixed costs there is only the width and height that are dynamic.

So a unit that is 1001mm x 801mm would cost £260.25 (£260 + 10p + 15p)

hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I ended up substantially rewriting your code. Let me know if you need explanations. I changed all the field names to make it easier and self explanatory what I did

Comment: just tried the example and it works perfect man thank you so much :) 

the only thing i noticed that didn't work is when choosing Primed (-£15) it doesn't minus the £15 but i'll try and figure that out. thanks again

Comment: It DOES subtract, but I then enforce the minimum of 260. Try adding slats and then primer

Comment: You can remove  `if (total < prices["base"]) total = prices["base"];` to allow for primer